# MySql date format with word

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli, date-formatting

I'm following documentation from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

This one gave me result:

```
WHERE  (DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%Y %m' ) BETWEEN '2014 03' AND '2014 06')
```

but this one does not:

```
WHERE  (DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%Y %M' ) BETWEEN '2014 March' AND '2014 June')
```

I want to use date like this: `April 2014`

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: What did you do wrong?  You thought that comparisons to strings somehow magically correspond to the semantics (meanings) of the words in the string.  The comparisons you are looking at are alphabetical, so nothing matches because "March" > "June".

Comment: You're comparing strings. `M` is greater than `J` in the alphabet, therefore 2014 March is GREATER than 2014 June.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I have solved this problem with PHP. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare strings. The comparisons you are looking at are alphabetical, so nothing matches because "March" > "June".

The comparison of two stings. `M` is greater than `J` in the alphabet therefore 2014 March is GREATER than 2014 June.

Don't ever try to use strings for comparison factors.